# Django check if date from post is between two dates from model

Tags: python, django

I'm not really experienced in Django, but now I am trying to develop simple project with model class like this:

```
class FacebookEvent(models.Model):
   start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

In view file - there's no problem when I want to get all objects where start_time is today, tomorrow or in any other date range (including hours):

```
my_date= request.POST.get('my_date','') # for eg. 2015-10-26
events = FacebookEvent.objects.all().filter(start_time__range=
    (datetime.combine(my_date,(datetime.min).time()), datetime.combine(my_date,(datetime.max).time()))).order_by('start_time')
```

but now i have to check if requested date (my_date) is between start_time and end_time from model.
I just have to do the same what I was doing before, but a little bit inversely...

It took me few hours, but still I can't find any concept how to solve this problem.
Anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for all replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure if I understand the question.

**If you have a model instance and a date:**

First you need to convert your date to a datetime.datetime object

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
my_date= request.POST.get('my_date','')
mdate = parse(mydate)
```

> Then you can use mdate to do logical comparisons. i.e:
>    mdate > fbEvent.start_time

**If you want model instances between dates**

```
 mdate = parse(mydate)   
events = FacebookEvent.objects.filter(start_time__gt=mdate, end_time__lt=mdate)
```

Comment: For more information http://blog.zdsmith.com/comparing-dates-and-datetimes-in-the-django-orm.html

Comment: Thank's - for me it's the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can do like:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date= request.POST.get('my_date','') # for eg. 2015-10-26
my_date = datetime.strptime(my_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

events = FacebookEvent.objects.filter(start_time__lt=my_date, end_time__gt=my_date).order_by('start_time')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you get started:

```
# assuming Sample is your model class and sampledate is your column to filter on
samples = Sample.objects.filter(sampledate__gt=datetime.date(2011, 1, 1), sampledate__lt=datetime.date(2011, 1, 31))
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly late to the party here, but if you're planning to use this `range` feature frequently, I highly recommend checking out the new [postgres range fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/). They have a lot of handy query filters right off the bat and provide a much cleaner, intuitive way to deal with ranges.